# Filtering a list by a property matching a property in another list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The assignment is pretty easy. Given a list of invoices and a list of accounts, I need to filter the former only keeping those with an active account related to them. An example of what it should behave like follows.

> Invoices: {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}, {"d", 4}
>   Accounts: {"a", 100}, {"c", 101}
>   Results: {"a", 1}, {"c", 3}

I resolved it using *Contains* but it failed on the EF not being able to execute such an complex query (there are other conditions as well and it's also possible that the EF isn't set up properly). Then I tried to fetch all the data and do the filtration on the client but it failed on exception overflow and was painstakingly slow.

After a night of balancing code quality versus performance by trial and horror, fighting weird exceptions I don't understand (yes, google gave a lot but nothing that made me more wise) and can't do anything about (pre-existing configuration to be accepted as-in), I've arrived at the following code.

```
List<Guid> guids = datas.Select(data => data.Id).ToList();
List<Invoice> invoices = context.Invoices
  .Where(invoice => condition_00)
  ...
  .Where(invoice => condition_99).ToList();
invoices = invoices.Where(invoice => guids.Any(guid => invoice.Id == guid)).ToList();
```

Frankly, I'm not satisfied with the steps and I feel that the right way is to perform the whole operation in a single whack. Supposing that we're not allowed to discuss the issues of how EF is set up and how the DB behaves, can anything be improved to work faster in the following request? Preferably, I want the DB to process it all by the magic of LINQ.

Comment: You should be able to do `invoices = invoices.Where(invoice => datas.Select(data => data.Id).Contains(invoice.Id)).ToList();`. What's the error you're getting when trying that? Also, what's `datas`? How is it declared?

Comment: The error message is "*The underlying provider failed on Open.*" with inner saying that the action is invalid in the transaction's current state. The variable *datas* is cust a class that has a property of type *Guid*. Just a representation of a table in SQL.

Comment: You're calling `Select` on it, so it has to be a collection. How exactly is it declared? Try using `context` directly.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I see what you're getting at. I'm also suspecting that the devil isn't in the LINQ query of mine. (I'm only allowed into certain parts and if you only have a hammer, everything's a nail.) The *datas* is actually *context.Donkeys.Where...* and the intersector is *context.Ponys.Where...* so it should work. Can that be an issue that everything is done within the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

What about using JOIN?

```
           List<List<object>> Invoices = new List<List<object>>() {
               new List<object>(){"a", 1}, 
               new List<object>(){"b", 2}, 
               new List<object>(){"c", 3}, 
               new List<object>(){"d", 4}
            };


            List<List<object>> Accounts = new List<List<object>>() {
               new List<object>(){"a", 100}, 
               new List<object>(){"c", 101}
            };


            var results = (from invoices in Invoices
                          join accounts in Accounts on invoices[0] equals accounts[0]
                          select new { name = invoices[0], id = invoices[1], total = accounts[1] })
                          .ToList();​
```